# Formatting string in python going wrong

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

Following is my code snippet.

```
bar = "Hello World"
print("%5s" % bar)
```

I am trying to print **Hello** from *bar*. But *%5s* is not working as it should.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: No - it's working as it should... `%5s` will pad - it won't truncate...

Comment: @JonClements: I don't follow you. Am I missing something ?

Comment: You can (ab)use `'%.5s'` but it's often clearer to just truncate the input... `bar[:5]` for instance...

Comment: `%5s` will make sure it's at *least* 5 characters (padding with a fill character (space by default) if needs be)... if it's more - then nothing happens

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of _%5s_ ? I thought it will behave exactly like `bar[:5]`.

Comment: As I said - it makes the width *at least* that amount... try `'%50s' % 'bob'`... If what you're formatting is longer - then nothing happens.

Comment: @JonClements: Gotcha ! The total field width will be as mentioned. If padding exceeds no of characters then string will be padded with _(padding - no of characters )_ spaces.

Comment: If you're not doing something more complicated in the formatting, then there's also `str.ljust` and `str.rjust` which are more explicit than `%-5s` or `%5s` etc... So `'bob'.rjust(50)` rather than `'%50s' % 'bob'`...

Comment: @JonClements: Thanks. That helped me understand and learn two more methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In following code:

```
bar = "Hello World"
print("%5s" % bar)
```

Total width of *bar* should be more than 5 characters otherwise *padding spaces* will be added as prefix.

Here padding is `5` but string length is `11`. So nothing will happen.

In following code:

```
bar = "Hello World"
print("%15s" % bar)
```

Padding is `15` which exceeds string length `11`. Hence `4` spaces will be added in beginning.

Output will be: `----Hello World`

`-` denotes one space.

Answer (score 2):

It is simpler to do this:

```
bar = "Hello World"

print (bar[:5])
```

using '%5s' will simply return the whole string because the string is >5 characters long, if you use '%20's for example you will get white space followed by the whole string, like so.

```
bar = "Hello World"
print("%20s" % bar)
>>>         Hello World
```

Comment: I am aware of slicing. I was trying to understand what that format does.

Comment: I believe that '%5s' will return the string 'Hello World' without any padding, this is because 'Hello World' is 11 characters long, if you change the number from '%5s' to say '%20s' the string will be padded with 9 spaces before 'Hello World' is displayed. Simply put, it adds white space before a string.

Comment: Yep. Your belief is true. My answer is based on same.

Answer (score 0):

%5s will pad the string with spaces if it is shorter than 5 characters
e.g.

```
>>> print("%5s" % "Hi")
   Hi
```

To truncate the string you can either use %.5s

```
>>> bar = "Hello World"
>>> print("%.5s" % bar)
Hello
```

or can slice the string as follows

```
>>> bar = "Hello World"
>>> print("%s" % bar[:5])
Hello
```